# Formatting List With Numbers as well as Definition and Explanation

Tags: html, css, list

I have a glossary list that I need to format as such:

1 Apple - Red juicy fruit

where both the 1 AND the definition (Apple) is in red and the explanation is in grey. Currently my the list looks like this : https://i.stack.imgur.com/MDIeP.jpg

The closest I have got is the "Goal/No Goal" definition but the problem here is I need the grey text to carry on underneath the beginning of the explanation and not the definition.

Here is the code for the list :

HTML:

```
<li class="dropdownAU_CNT"><a href="#" data-toggle="dropdownAU_CNT">G<i class="icon-arrow"></i></a>
                            <ul class="dropdownAU_CNT-menu">
                                <li>
                                    <ul>
                                        <li><div class="divTextRedDef">Goals Home Team –</div><div class="divText"> Home team exact number of goals at the end of normal time.</div>
                                        </li>
                                        <div class="divSpacer10"></div>
                                        <li><div class="divTextRedDef">Goals Away Team –</div><div class="divText"> Away team exact number of goals at the end of normal time.</div>
                                        </li>
                                        <div class="divSpacer10"></div>
                                        <li><span class="divRedCharacter">Goal/No Goal –</span> Goal is the option of choosing both teams to score. No Goal is the opposite option of both teams not to score, 
                                             so either only 1 team scores or neither teams scores at all.
                                        </li>
                                        <div class="divSpacer10"></div>
                                        <li><div class="divTextRedDef">Goal/No Goal 1st Half (GG/NG) –</div><div class="divText"> Same as Goal/No Goal option for the first half only.</div>
                                        </li>
                                        <div class="divSpacer10"></div>
                                        <li><div class="divTextRedDef">Goal/No Goal 2nd Half (GG/NG) -</div><div class="divText"> Same as Goal/No Goal option for the second half only.</div>
                                        </li>
                                        <div class="divSpacer10"></div>
                                    </ul>
                                </li>
                            </ul>
                        </li
```

CSS:

```
.divTextRed  { font-family:Arial; text-align:justify; font-size:12px; margin:0px 10px 0px 10px; text-transform:none; font-weight: normal; color: #c81018; }         
.divTextRedDef { font-family:Arial; text-align:justify; font-size:12px; margin:0px 10px 0px 10px; text-transform:none; font-weight: normal; color: #c81018; float:left; display:table-row;}
.dropdownAU_CNT-menu li ul li { font-family:Arial; font-size:12px; margin-top: 2px; display: table; position:relative; list-style:none; margin:2px 0 6px 2em; margin-bottom:10px; text-indent: -44px;}
.dropdownAU_CNT-menu li ul li:before { color:#ad0c10 !important; content: counters(item, ".") " "; counter-increment: item; display: inline-block; text-align:right; padding-right:10px; width:2em; top:-2px; left:-2em; margin-right:10px; color:#ad0c10 !important; }
```

Any help would be much appreciated!!

Comment: are you trying somehing of that kind ?http://codepen.io/anon/pen/DoFAn  Why don't you use definition list ?

Comment: Sort of, except that if the explanation text runs longer than one line it should continue from the beginning of the explanation rather than the red definition

Comment: okay, so a definition list + + float and overflow will do like this ? http://codepen.io/anon/pen/yLzFu add numbers http://codepen.io/anon/pen/tFfjI

Comment: Im not sure if when you view it on your side it renders correctly but on my side it indents each list item a bit more than the one before ?

Comment: float may need to be cleared : dt {clear:left}

Comment: http://codepen.io/anon/pen/tILoJ

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1) Use an absolutely positioned pseudo element for the counter

2) Use an absolutely positioned pseudo element for the definition

3) If you want the text to run under the explanation - use `padding-left` on the list item

**[FIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/danield770/QLrax/1/)**

```
ul {
    counter-reset: itemCounter;
    list-style:none;
}
li {
    padding-left: 75px;
    counter-increment: itemCounter;
    position:relative;
}
li:before {
    content: counter(itemCounter);
    position: absolute;
    left:0;
    color: purple;
}
li:after {
    content: attr(data-item)  ' - \00a0';
    position: absolute;
    left:15px;
    top:0;
}
```

Comment: I cant use a list style type as the numbers need to be styled and I don't know of any way to style list numbers other than setting the content to a counter using a before pseudo element

Comment: @user3631090 - I updated the solution using counters - take a look

Answer (score 0):

If you want to have the explanation under the definition:

```
<ul>
    <li>
        1 Apple - <div class="divText">Home team exact number of goals at the end of normal time.</div>
    </li>

    <li>
        2 Apple - <div class="divText">Red juicy fruit.</div>
    </li>

</ul>
```

### css

```
ul li { color: #ad0c10; margin:0 0 10px;}
ul li div.divText {color: #c81018;}
```

btw.. You shouldn't use DIV's between LI's

Comment: The client unfortunately doesn't want that :( They want it to be all one line and if the text runs over it must run underneath the explanation only